# Redirect from embedded controller

Tags: php, symfony

I use [embedded controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) to render form that's used on multiple pages:

**Twig**

```
{% render 'Bundle:Controller:someForm' %}
```

**Controller**

```
public function someFormAction()
{
    // Some logic

    ...

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        ...

        $this->get('session')->setFlash('successful', "Woey!");

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'));
    }

    return $this->render('Bundle:Template:form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

I need to redirect back to homepage after the form was successfully submitted as a part of [post-redirect-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) design pattern. If I use it as I described above, I'll get exception as response from embedded controller was 302 instead of 200 (at least I expect it works like this).

Is it possible to redirect normally in such scenario? Or am I approaching the situation (with form that's rendered on multiple pages) from totally wrong angle?

Comment: Hey Ondrej did you ever manage to find a clean way to achieve this (or your other question about form re-use on another page)? I'm just curious since I'm facing exactly the same issue. Seems like it could be a common problem if you have a site-wide search form or some such. Only way I can think of is by posting to the someFormAction route directly and then using a redirect back to the original URL and storing the form variables in the session... seems a tad dirty though.

Comment: It seems it works as intended like this. I'm using the same technique as you described. I did some further research and you cannot even access the parent scope from within embedded action. That would help a lot.

Comment: Ok thanks. I had thought that using the session might be the way to go - if you look at the inbuilt Login Form Authentication it does the same (stores the username and password field in session) and then redirects to some URL either in the config or via a hidden field (I think). It would be so much cleaner if an embedded action could redirect by POSTing to the parent action route, shame it doesn't work though. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: http://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2517 Fabien says a redirect isn't possible and that he isn't sure they want to add support for that feature at this time. (Just putting this here for anyone else who comes across the question). Also for the record I abandoned my "using the session" idea because it made the form controller code quite complex. I ended up just writing a form handler and including it in the flow of the parent controller.

Comment: Did any of you find a proper way of doing this? Still can't figure it out after reading your comments.

Comment: Define proper. You can post to another url, save cookie with referer and then redirect back. I'm not sure if there's easier way with newer versions of Symfony.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to make it official answer, [Fabien doesn't think Symfony2 will ever support this feature](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2517).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you. I use this to show 404 pages if a resource was not found in an embedded controller.

```
try
{
    return $this->render('MyBundle:Table:list.html.twig', $data);
}
catch(\Twig_Error_Runtime $e)
{
    if($e->getPrevious() instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException();
    }
    else throw $e;
}
```

You could make a `RedirectHttpException`, which would hold your redirection data, and throw it in your embedded controller. Then redirect in your parent controller.