# Redirect from embedded controller in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have two controllers, say **loginAction()** and **registerAction** embedded into the index page (**index.html.twig**) as so:

```
// index.html.twig
{% block header %}
{% if app.session.get('loggedin') is null%}
<div class="linear_form_holder">
    {% render "AppBaseBundle:Core:login" %}
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

now, in the login controller, i am using this :

```
public function loginAction(Request $request) {
    if ($password == $record->getPassword()) {
    /* then set the session variables */
        $session->set('loggedin', '1');
        $session->set('username',$record->getUsername());
        $session->set('userid',$record->getId());
    /* and grant access to the profile */
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'),301);
    }
    else 
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('main_page'),301);
}
```

But, i am getting this error:

**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Error when rendering "http://localhost/web/app_dev.php/" (Status code is 301).") in AppBaseBundle:Core:index.html.twig at line 6.**

How do i do redirection in an embedded controller?

Comment: How should an embedded controller be able to handle a redirect in your opinion?

Comment: I'm not sure about the use of the 'render' function within your twig template. What is the intention here? By the time you get to your twig template you should be outputting html, if you need to redirect, you should be doing it _before_ you get to this stage. It looks to me like you are attempting to redirect from _within_ your twig template - is this correct?

Comment: @kissmyface : yes i think that is right... (although i did not view it that way)

Comment: or, is there a BETTER way to embed the login form in the index page ?

Comment: You could just _include_ the login form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect from embedded controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984429/redirect-from-embedded-controller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget redirecting from sub-request.

The solution is: 
 1. Let the form you create in your sub-template post to your parent controller. (form can still be created in different controller, no problem)
 2. in parent controller check your request to catch the info coming in from the subcontroller and check if the info of your sub-template form comes in.

eg:

```
$myPostInfo = $request->request->all()
if(isset($myPostInfo['acme_userbundle_login'])) {
  die('form has been submitted');
  // here you can do the stuff one would do on a committed form
}
```

For login it is best to add it to your base template, but when you have forms called by AJAX, this is the solution I use.

Good luck

Any questions? Keep me posted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I hope this is useful for peeps in the future who are working with Symfony2.
Unfortunately (or thankfully), I threw symfony out the window some years back due to it being an incredibly slow place to do any serious development.

Answer (score 3):

It's been quite a long time since I asked this question, and as can be seen from the comments, or if you just read the code, the design was horribly flawed. I was just starting with Symfony2, and the MVC architecture in general, so it was a lot later I realized why I was never going to receive an answer for this question :P

Since then, I've moved on to a lot of different frameworks and completely ditched the convoluted ways of Symfony to embrace node, backbone, angularjs and whatnot, and life is a hell lot simpler.

Anyways, since this question still seems to be gathering some views and stray upvotes from (i am guessing) started in Symfony, here is the fixed code, and some reasoning (I've pulled this from my GIT repo, and this was still a long time ago, i.e., teeth-cutting phase, so I'm not very sure if this is a good way, but whatever)

### In your controller

```
public function indexAction() {
  $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();    
  if($session->get('loggedin') != null ) {
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'),301);
  } else {
    $loginData = array();
    $loginForm = $this->createFormBuilder($loginData)
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('password', 'password')
        ->getform();
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Core:index.html.twig',
               array('loginForm' => $loginForm->createView()) );
  }
}
```

### In your view

```
{% extends '::basetemplate.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}PAGE TITLE{% endblock %}

  {% block header %}
  {% if app.session.get('loggedin') is null %}
  <div class="linear_form_holder">
    {% include "AppBundle:Core:login.html.twig" with {'form':loginForm} %}
  </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

---

Things to take away:

1. Don't make recursive calls like `loginAction` redirecting to `main-page`, which calls `loginAction` again, like in my question: Not only is the code in my question flawed, but excessive recursion will kill the server anyways, so you might not get a clue what's wrong. Try to keep it simpler.
2. Abstract out the login and registration and other forms away, and don't use templates for them. Bind them to a model, and use formBuilder for generating the forms.

   Extra advice: If you can, switch to newer technologies such as nodejs or maybe Go (I haven't tried it yet). Initially the investment in learning is a lot, but you'll reap its benefits over time. Feel free to disregard this extra advice.

Have fun

:)